# iptables rule not taken in account (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I'm running a forum and we are being hammered by some rogue server.

I try to ban its IP using:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 5.45.77.40 -j DROP
```

Once this is done, `iptables -L | grep '5.45.77.40'` replies:

```
DROP       all  --  5.45.77.40           anywhere
```

and `iptables -S` lists, among others:

```
-A INPUT -s 5.45.77.40/32 -j DROP
```

However looking at the apache server log, the nuisance can still reach the apache server. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Server has been set up by hosting company, and runs UFW (Uncomplicated FireWall) above iptables, so the rules I added were overriden by the UFW ones.
The solution is to use:

```
ufw insert 1 deny from 5.45.77.40
```

(to make sure that the rule is processed before more generic ones)